# SSRS Extra blank pages on PDF export with hidden tablix element

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that has 3 sperate tables, one of which can be hidden based on the user selection from a parameter to export it as XLSX/PDF. The table is hidden if the user selects PDF as it is a large table with ~30 columns. The issue I am running into is even when this large table is hidden on the PDF selection (utilizing an expression in the hidden property), it still leads to multiple blank pages being inserted on the export.

I believe the issue is that the entire report body extends well beyond the margins (77in width) because of this large table. I have confirmed that the other two tables alone do not print any extra pages when the third larger table is removed. I have set the margins for the other tables and selected the consume white space property.

Any ideas on how to navigate this? I can't shrink the third large table size as users who select XLSX, the columns would be smashed together/very small in width.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the Paper Size in the Report Properties?

Comment: Hi Diego, yes I have set the paper size to 11 x 8.5 for landscape orientation.

Comment: I would recommend changing that to Legal size (14 x 8.5), I had a similar issue and that was my solution to the problem. It still prints fine in 11 x 8.5, but I would double check if that works for you.